# Smart Mailbox Folder not displaying mail

Tags: macos, mail.app, smart-folders

I've got two smart mailboxes named *NEW eric@* and *NEW ericgorr@* which contain only new message for corresponding email accounts. I have placed these two smart mailboxes into a smart mailbox folder named *Personal*. When I select *Personal*, I see that it will show me the new messages contained in the smart mailboxes it contains as shown in the image:

[image: Working Smart Mailbox Folder]

So far, so good. However, I created another smart mailbox folder called *Personal 2*. When I move the smart mailbox *NEW eric@* into *Personal 2* and select *Personal 2*, no messages are displayed as shown in the image:

[image: Not working Smart Mailbox Folder]

Anyone know why? Any know what can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The update (released today) for Mountain Lion, version 10.8.5, is supposed to, among other things:

> Fix an issue that may prevent Mail from displaying messages.

I'd be curious to see, since this issue was never solved, if this update resolves it.